# Laravel 5 session array update

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having trouble while updating session array value in laravel 5. Here is my function,

```
public function postCartItemAdd()
{
    $id = Request::input('id');
    Session::push('items', $id);

    dd(Session::all());
}
```

Instead of pushing a new id into the array it just replaces the existing value leaving single item. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the session is saved as a flash data. So, you need to save the session whenever you push the data.

```
$request->session()->push('user.items', 'item1');
$request->session()->push('user.items', 'item2');
$request->session()->save();
```

Answer (score 0):

umm i think you used it wrong,

see the [DOC](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/session#session-usage)

it says

```
Session::push('user.teams', 'developers');
```

`user` is the array and we gonna put a value `developers` to that array with `teams` key

so then you need to use it in your case as,

```
Session::push('items.id', $id);
```

**OR** if you need to maintain `items` as an array with default keys like `0,1,2,3...` to put the `ids`, then `items` should be an array

so there should be a something like,

```
Session::put('items', []);
```

then you can use `Session::push('items', $id);`

if you need to push ids in to same array as you tried.

Answer (score 0):

or try this

```
$items = Session::pull('items');
$items[] = $id;
Session::push('items', $items);
```